# Ajax добавление данных в базу из table

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, ajax

есть таблица, как записать из нее данные из строк, у которых `data-new="1"` в базу mysql?

```
<table  class="heavyTable" contenteditable="true">
                    <thead>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th>Due Date</th>
                        <th>RUB</th>
                        <th>EUR</th>
                        <th>Debit</th>
                        <th>Credit</th>
                        <th>Balanse</th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr data-id="" data-new="0">
                            <td>1</td>
                            <td>2</td>
                            <td>3</td>
                            <td>1</td>
                            <td>2</td>
                            <td>3</td>
                            <td>3</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr data-id="" data-new="0">
                            <td>1</td>
                            <td>2</td>
                            <td>3</td>
                            <td>1</td>
                            <td>2</td>
                            <td>3</td>
                            <td>3</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr data-id="" data-new="0">
                            <td>1</td>
                            <td>2</td>
                            <td>3</td>
                            <td>1</td>
                            <td>2</td>
                            <td>3</td>
                            <td>3</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr data-id="" data-new="1">
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

получается массив, а с массивом делайте что вам надо

```js
let table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];
let arr = table.children[1].children;
let results = [];
for (let j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr[j].attributes.length; i++) {
    if (arr[j].attributes[i].name == 'data-new' && arr[j].attributes[i].value == 1) {
      for (let k = 0; k < arr[j].children.length; k++) {
        results.push(arr[j].children[k].innerHTML)
      }
      break;
    }
  }
}
console.log(results);
```

Comment: а можно через json? чтобы записывать ключи наименование полей, взяв атрибут ячейки data-name и значение ячейки?